# onRequestPermissionsResult not called from AppCompatActivity on Android 6

Tags: java, android, runtime, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

My activity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 55;
```

Then, on create:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
     if(getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND) || getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE))
        {if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, (android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            }
}
```

The problem is that override method `onRequestPermissionsResult` is never called on Android 6. However, it works fine on Android 7 and Android 8.

My activity is defined as follows:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:noHistory="false"
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of links you might also check but I do not think onRequestPermissionsResult works in Android 6 and in you code I never see that line used LINKS BELOW

http://androidkeeda.com/android-marshmallow-permissions-example

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `noHistory=true` in `AndroidManifest` for this activity (or `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`), otherwise the activity would be dismissed on Android 6 and would not receive result callbacks including `onRequestPermissionsResult`.